# node.js: How can i get cookie value by cookie name from request?

Tags: node.js

How i can get cookie value by cookie name?

`res.headers['set-cookie']` returns all cookies.

i need like `res.headers['set-cookie']['cookieName']`

Comment: `res` is typically the name of the response object, not the request object, and `set-cookie` is a response header, not a request header. Your question title and body appear to be talking about different things. What do you really want to get?

Comment: Are you using any kind of library to help you parse HTTP requests and make responses? e.g. Express?

Comment: @Quentin i'm using **request** module and trying to get cookie 'sessionID' after get request

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I have found this solution may work for you

```
var get_cookies = function(request) {
  var cookies = {};
  request.headers && request.headers.cookie.split(';').forEach(function(cookie) {
    var parts = cookie.match(/(.*?)=(.*)$/)
    cookies[ parts[1].trim() ] = (parts[2] || '').trim();
  });
  return cookies;
};
```

and then you can use

```
get_cookies(request)['cookieName']
```

But if you are using express.I will suggest you

```
var express = require('express');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());
```

then to get cookie value.You can

```
req.cookies['cookieName']
```

Hope this help. I found these solutions and worked for me.

Comment: This is working only when you make request to the js file. How do you make it possible to the html file.

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks!

Comment: First approach totally works, but I ended up going the Express cookie-parser route. It felt more "proper".

Answer (score 3):

Typescript version of `Rajan Lagah`'s answer with some more checks:

```
const getCookiesAsCollection = function (rawCookie: string): Record<string, string> {
    const cookies: Record<string, string> = {};
    rawCookie && rawCookie.split(";").forEach(function (cookie: string) {
        const parts: RegExpMatchArray | null = cookie.match(/(.*?)=(.*)$/);
        if (parts && parts.length) {
            cookies[parts[1].trim()] = (parts[2] || "").trim();
        }
    });
    return cookies;
};
```